# Конкатенация в условии

Tags: php

Как сделать так, чтобы выводилась строка 'Перед условие 1 после' ?

Сейчас выводится только условие 1

```
 $text = 'Что-то';
 $q = 'Перед ' . $text ? 'условие 1' : 'условие 2' . ' после';
 echo $q;
```

Comment: `$q .= ' после';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тернарный оператор не совместим с интуицией. Проще всего с этим бороться с помощью скобок. Там, где как вам кажется, должна быть проверка и выбор варианта, там и оберните всё в скобки:

```
$q = 'Перед ' . ($text ? 'условие 1' : 'условие 2') . ' после';
```

Иначе сейчас у вас получается вот такая логика с точки зрения пхп:

```
$q = ('Перед ' . $text) ? ('условие 1') : ('условие 2' . ' после');
```

И, т.к. в левой части у вас точно истина, вы получаете центральную часть как результат.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 'Что-то';
$q = 'Перед ' . ($text ? 'условие 1' : 'условие 2') . ' после';
echo $q;
```